# Two different public IPs

Tags: ip, network-discovery

I'm using Jenkins in my company, one master node and two slaves hosted in the office. master on hosted Google Cloud VM. To improve security, I created a restriction so only our office Jenkins slaves were able to connect to Jenkins master - I set a firewall rule in Google Platform networking settings to limit accessibility to `tcp:34903` port used by JNLP (protocol for communication between Jenkins nodes). It was working fine for a few months, but recently we moved our office. I corrected the rule yesterday (changed the IP), but today I noticed that one of the machines is disconnected.  I switched off the rule - it is working back. So I started checking what external IP I have for my machines, and depends on site/service used for discovering the public IP I get one of two IPs. When I allowed connecting from both of addresses, it is working fine.

The questions are:

1. why I get two different address (completely different classes) depends on service I use for checking?
2. why two machines from the same network are treated differently (is Google spreading IP discovery to multiple services)?

Services reporting address A:

- `curl ifconfig.me`
- `curl ident.me`
- `curl icanhazip.com`
- `curl ipecho.net/plain`
- `curl ipinfo.io/ip`
- `dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com`
- `dig +short o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @ns1.google.com`

Services reporting address B:

- `curl ip.appspot.com`
- `curl https://wtfismyip.com/text`
- `curl ifconfig.co`

The website that listings all of those commands:
https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-find-out-public-ip-address-from-command-line-on-linux

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host configurations or protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Comment: This is really something you must sort out with your ISP. We can only make guess which is not really useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've certainly seen public wifi route different services out through different border routers: TCP to port 80 went out of one machine, SSH another, and UDP another still.  So recipient saw different source addresses depending on which service.  I've also seen backup lines come out of different IP addresses, though normally on purpose.

What you're describing sounds consistent with a router doing NAT out of two outside interfaces, with routing depending on the target AS.  Or a tunnel with another NAT egress point.  Might you or your ISP have done such on purpose or by accident?

I suggest checking your border router and your ISP.